# Combining (ALL individual) Elements of an Arrays in a Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

The Dictionary is defined as

```
var weekActualPowerZoneTimes: [String:[Int]]()

weekActualPowerZoneTimes:
[
"Ride"  : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
"Run"   : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
"Swim"  : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
"Other" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

Goal:  combine these arrays to become one. Namely, I'm looking for this output

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

The Arrays to be sum, technically should be of equal size, but there could be a chance that they would not be depending on user preference. (Some user may choose to have 7 Power Zones, some may use 5 in the future)

I am currently able to sum 2 arrays using this

```
let arrayResult:[Int] = zip(array1,array2).map(+)
```

but getting stuck on how to sum a possible arbitrary number of arrays (eg: User may only be doing Run/Swim or Run/Swim/Ride or Others/Swim) in the dictionary.

Update:
I tried this, which works, but only if I define the initial "combined" Array

```
var combined = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

let aa =
[
"Ride"  : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
"Run"   : [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
"Swim"  : [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
"Other" : [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

for (index,values) in aa.values.enumerated(){
    print(index, values)
    combined = zip(combined,values).map(+)
    print("\(combined)") // [10, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
}
```

But it will result in [] if the initial `combined` array is defined as

```
var combined = [Int]()
```

Comment: Can you certify that the array are of equal count?

Comment: @Larme By right they "would" be, but there's a possibility that they are not. (I'll add that into the question)

Comment: I notice that you call the dictionary `week...` but there are 8 elements per array?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes. It's a Weekly Data of Time(secs) In Power Zones. There are between 5 to 7 to 10 power zones (depending on if who's your coach or whose training philosophy you're adhering to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this variant of zipping on reddit that works for arrays of different length

```
func add(a: [Int], b: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    zip(a, b).map(+) + (a.count < b.count ? b[a.count ..< b.count] : a[b.count ..< a.count])
}
```

So with that we can loop over the values of the dictionary

```
var combined = [Int]()
weekActualPowerZoneTimes.values.forEach {
    combined = add(a: combined, b: $0)
}
```

Using a `forEach` loop over values means we can have any number of values and the `add` function means the values arrays can be of different length